# What's wrong with my self-signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, self-signed-certificate

I want to create a self-sign certificate on a Windows Server 2012 R2, just to test and try it.

I have no error on my certificate information but when I browse to http://localhost, I see the browser red bar, meaning something is wrong with the certificate.

[image: Browser warning (red bar)]

I tried many references like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/), but I can not find my mistake.

Is that a way to see logs or trace errors?

Comment: The very nature of a self-signed certificate is that it's untrusted by the browser, because it's not signed by a legitimate CA.

You can opt to [explicitly trust one](https://www.google.com/search?q=trusting+a+self-signed+certificate+in+internet+explorer) on a per-certificate basis. Any difficulties with that process are **off-topic** here, and should be directed somewhere like SuperUser with *specific* details on what you've attempted.

Comment: @ceejayoz ,then why this option is available on windows?when browsers never trust to this types of ssl or....

Comment: Self-signed certs are perfectly fine for local development work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The certificate was not issued to localhost. The certificate was issued to WIN-CN2DB9TT88P. Those are not the same. Browsing to http://localhost in your web browser is not the same as http://WIN-CN2DB9TT88P. You can trust a self-signed certificate if you want to, just by importing the cert into your Trusted CAs store, but it's only valid for the very specific name that is on the certificate.

Comment: When i created this certification there was not any option to select "issued to", how can i handle it?

Comment: @motevallizadeh Just use your favorite search engine. No rocket science involved.

Comment: @gf_ I've been searching and ended up here. Still cant find a way to do this.